# How to find element which caused event because of jquery .live

Tags: jquery

How can I find  ID of the element which caused an event as a consequence of .live (jQuery method) ?

The following is an example :

```
$("form[data-f=true]").live("submit", function (evt) {
    /*
      If I have <input type="submit" name="Submit1" data-f="true" /> and this button is clicked, then I want to know it's Submit1 button.
    */
});
```

I checked evt and its properties/fields but no luck.

Comment: Note, as of jQuery 1.7, `$.live` is deprecated. Use [`$.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this,

```
event.target //DOM object.

evt.target.id  //id of source element.

sourceElement = $(evt.target.id); // will get you jQuery object
```

*Note, as of jQuery 1.7, $.live is deprecated. Use $.on instead.*

To get the element within for which caused the submit.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('submit', 'form[data-f=true]', function() { 

    var elem = $("input[type=submit][clicked=true]");
    alert(elem.attr('id'));
    // DO WORK

});

$("form[data-f=true] input[type=submit]").click(function() {
    $("input[type=submit]", $(this).parents("form")).removeAttr("clicked");
    $(this).attr("clicked", "true");
});
```

Comment: You can pass an element reference directly into `$()` - no need to look it up by its ID, adding extra cost to the operation of constructing a new jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanSampson, I was about to tell and was writing, thanks for guidance.

Comment: It doesn't work in IE10. evt.target.id returns the form not the button I clicked. Any idea how to do it also in IE10 ? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the event handler, `this` points to the generator of the event

```
$("form[data-f=true]").live("submit", function (evt) {
    $(this); // is the event generator.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The current element will be applied to the handler function so you can simply use `this.id`:

```
$("form[data-f=true]").live("submit", function (evt) {
    alert(this.id)
});
```

You can also interrogate the event itself to see which element raised the event:

```
$("form[data-f=true]").live("submit", function (evt) {
    alert(evt.target.id)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `submit` event is emitted by the form itself, so the `.target` is going to be the form that is being submitted. If you want to know which button inside the form was last clicked, you need to bind to an event that bubbles up from the buttons, such as `click`:

```
$("form").on("click", ":submit", function (event) {
    console.log(event.target); // The submit button last clicked
});​
```

From here you can choose to submit the form, or not. This handler responds only to click events that occur on the `form` element, proceeding from a `submit` button within.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5sQZ5/1/

You could dynamically add references to the last-clicked element within the form, so that within the `submit` handler on the form you can determine who raised the event:

```
// Tell submit buttons to update parenting forms when clicked
$(":submit").on("click", function (event) {
    $(this).closest("form").data("target", this);
});

// When a form is submitted, find last associated submit button
$("form").on("submit", function (event) {
    console.log( $(this).data("target") ); 
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5sQZ5/2/